# Is there any AI model that predicts short-term stock price well?

Tags: time-series, forecasting

One simple way of predicating short-term stock price is to simply take the average price of the previous few days.

I wonder if there is some AI model/methods which can do better than this using only previous prices as input?

Comment: If it existed, it would probably be so widely used that any prediction, say a price rise in 5 minutes, would push up the price so that price increase disappears. See the [efficient markets hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Efficient_markets_hypothesis). So any such AI model will be subjective and carry risk.

Comment: Check the follow up! https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/39594/are-there-public-examples-of-ai-models-that-predicted-short-term-price-well?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attempt-wise, yes. All big players (e.g. J.P. Morgan) in the stock market who do automatic trading utilize reinforcement learning systems, which may contain components for short-term prediction.

But as @miguelmorin commented, if a simple algorithm ever exists, it would be so widely adopted until any gain from it disappear - that is, totally wrong predictions.

AFAIK, in long run, the only winners in short-term trading are those who can hire dozens of experts to build reinforcement systems, which are hosted on multi-million hardware, listening to thousands of market signals coming in from dark fibers 24/7, plus algorithms which can digest and place orders in less than 1 second (perhaps faster than our eyes seeing a price and our brain perceiving it). So, good luck!